# Calculating Resistor Value in Voltage Divider

Tags: circuit-design, component-selection

I am trying to reverse an equation to find the optimal resistor value in a voltage divider. But, when I try to reverse it, it never comes out right and I mess it up.

This is the equation:
$$V_{out}^{DC}= \frac{R_{2}}{R_{1} +R_{2}}*V_{in}^{DC}$$

How do I get the value of R2 if:

$$R_{1}=330\Omega$$
$$V_{out}^{DC}=4.5V$$
$$V_{in}^{DC}=9V$$

Comment: Rearranging this is basic algebra. Hint: times both sides by (R1+R2).

Comment: I usually work out the current through the resistor you do know to produce the voltage drop across it that you do know, using I=V1/R1. The unknown resistor must pass the same current and produce the other voltage drop that you also know, so that's found from R2=V2/I.

Comment: Since you want the output voltage to be half the input voltage, both resistors must be the same value, if no significant current is drawn from the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :
$$V_o = \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}*V_i$$
$$V_o*(R_1 + R_2) = R_2 * V_1$$
$$V_o*R_1 = R_2*(V_i-V_o)$$
$$R_2 = \frac{V_o*R_1}{V_i-V_o}$$

---

By the way, the output voltage is exactly the half of the input. This said, both resistor has to be the same. This statement isn't true if a load is apply at the output.